# Could not start bundle mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.6.2

Tags: apache-karaf

```
2016-02-01 15:02:19,152 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel  | BootFeaturesInstaller            | 20 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 3.0.5 | Error installing boot features
java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.6.2 in feature(s) de-support-0.0.0, swagger-2.11-6.1.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jackson.module.scala [274]: Unable to resolve 274.0: missing requirement [274.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer)(version>=2.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

I am getting above exception, while starting karaf even after providing

```
<bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.6.2</bundle>
```

in features.xml file.

Comment: You need atleast the bundle jackson-module-paranamer

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this message because one of your bundles imports the package com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer but you have not included a bundle in your feature which exports this package. A search for com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer brings up the pom for [Jackson Paranamer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-paranamer/blob/master/pom.xml) which shows that it exports the package that you need (look at the osgi.export property). So add:

```
<bundle>mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-paranamer/2.6.2</bundle>
```

to your feature in your features.xml

Comment: Added above one, but still getting same exception. Adding nested cause  below.                                                                                                                   caused by: Unable to resolve 275.0: missing requirement [275.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.inject)]
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]

Comment: OK great, that means the first dependency error has been fixed by adding that to your features.xml. Now you have exactly the same error but OSGi wants a different package, following what I did for the first error, what do you think you need to add to your features.xml?

Comment: It is not exactly resolved, I also got earlier exception                                 java.lang.Exception: Could not start bundle mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.6.2 in feature(s) de-support-0.0.0, swagger-2.11-6.1.0

Comment: When you restart karaf does that exception occur again? and can you see if the bundle is started if you do a bundle-list from the commend line?

Comment: After karaf clean, I found the same exception in the log file and  from the command line, when I typed list, I have observed that com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jackson.module.scala
Jackson-module-paranamer are in installed mode.

Comment: Initial exception was 2016-02-04 15:54:49,598 | WARN  | FelixStartLevel  | AetherBasedResolver              | 3 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | Error resolving artifactcom.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.2:Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.2 in karaf-system (file:G:/DM_HOME/delivery-engine-3.0.0/system/)
shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.2 in karaf-system (file:G:/DM_HOME/delivery-engine-3.0.0/system/)

Comment: To resolve above exception, till now I have added  mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-base/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.11/2.6.2
mvn:com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-paranamer/2.6.2 to features.xml